# An oil-pipe has to connect the oil-well O and the factory F, between which there is a river whose banks are parallel.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

@JonathanZ **Thanks for going all the way to help me out.**

An oil-pipe has to connect the oil-well O and the factory F, between
which there is a river whose banks are parallel. The pipe must cross
the river perpendicular to the banks. Find the position and nature of
the shortest such pipe and justify your answer.

I tried out this problem with some numbers and got the idea of path of minimum pipe length. How can I do it more rigorously?

This is what I got through my intuition. I think blue one is the minimal path.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The portion crossing the river is a fixed length. So "fold away" the river, i.e. mentally move line m over until it's on top of line l, so only the land portion of the path is visible. Can you minimize that length?

Comment: Oh, and think of everything to the right of m moving over too. It would be easy to show you what I mean if we were both looking at the same piece of actual, physical paper, but it's hard to know if my description is clear over the internet.

Comment: It's hard to visualize.

Comment: Okay, imagine your figure is drawn on a sheet of paper. Cut along lines m and l, and take the center strip (the river), and set it to one side. All of the paths have the same length crossing the river, so that portion plays no role in finding the shortest....

Comment: Now, push the other two pieces together, so that lines m and l are on top of each other. Look at the parts of each path that are now left. One of them should clearly be the shortest. If you're having trouble visualizing it, I'd suggest actually drawing your diagram on a piece of paper and actually cut out the river and push the two other pieces together.

Comment: By the way, I don't see how the blue path is uniquely defined. Yes, it's between the yellow and the red paths, but there are many paths that lie between them, and i don't see what distinguishes the blue one.

Comment: The blue path passes through the midpoint of line joining AC and yes I am doing it on a piece of paper. Let's experiment it.

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't pick that up from your diagram, but that does define the blue path uniquely. However, I don't think that always gives the right answer, although I'm not sure. Let's see what the paper cutting leads you to...

Comment: I got some pictures

Comment: Do you have discord?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145983/discussion-between-jonathanz-supports-monicac-and-samar).

Comment: Hey, nice final images. Isn't the "fold the river out of the way" trick cool? (And thanks for the call out .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Oil and factory]
Since we just want to know where to cross the river wrt to factory I have set the y coordinate of the factory to 1.

$d_1^2=a^2+x^2$

$d_2^2=b^2+(1-x)^2$

$y=d_1+d_2=\sqrt{(a^2+x^2 )}+\sqrt{(b^2+(1-x)^2 )}$

Note that w does not appear here, so it doesn't matter. We can set it to zero and looking at the diagram the answer becomes obvious, but let's just verify that:

We need to find the x that minimises y

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+\sqrt{b^2+(1-x)^2})}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}-\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{b^2+(1-x)^2}}=0$

$\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{b^2+(1-x)^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$

${1-x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}={x}{\sqrt{b^2+(1-x)^2}}$

$(1-x)^2(a^2+x^2)-x^2(b^2+(1-x)^2)=0$

$(a^2   - b^2 ) x^2- 2 a^2  x + a^2=0$

$x=\frac{a}{a+b}$ or $x=\frac{a}{a-b}$

Only the first one makes sense for a minimum so the other must be a max (check by getting 2nd derivative)

So pick x so that it is in the proportion a/(a+b) of the y distance to the factory, i.e. on a straight line to the factory if the river was not there.

Comment: We can also check that angle at $O$ and $F$ are same. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent graphic!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw two lines perpendicular to the river, one through $O$, one through $F$.
If they coincide, that's already the path of mininal lenght.
Else, mark points $O'$ and $F'$ on their respective lines, each moved towards the river by an amount equal to the rivers width.
Connect $O$ and $F'$ with a line and mark point $C_1$ where this line crosses the river bank near $O$.
Connect $O'$ and $F$ with a line and mark point $C_2$ where this line crosses the river bank near $F$.

The two segments $OC_1$ and $C_2F$ are parallel, and of combined length $OF'=O'F$, which is the minimal distance in case of a river with zero width; and in case the river does have width, its crossing pipe is always of length equal to the rivers width.

The pipe of minimal length follows the chain $OC_1C_2F$

Comment: This is the same length that I got through intuition but how can we prove it?

Answer (score 0):

PROOF

Place the two 'diagonal' pipes end to end. Combined in this way they have to cover a fixed distance perpendicular to the river (say $L$) and a fixed distance parallel to the river (say $M$). The total of their lengths is therefore at least $\sqrt(L^2+M^2)$ and this is achieved only when the two pipes form a straight line.

In your diagram the two diagonal sections must therefore be parallel. The pipe from $A$ must therefore head towards a point a distance $x$ to the left of $C$ and the pipe from $C$ must  head towards a point a distance $x$ to the right of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Cross the river 'first' and then join the two endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal crossing is  solid green, the solid red one is not optimal.

[image: optimal crossing]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore river width at first by a river width shift  and later restore with a shift vector of opposite sense.

S is start point and G is goal or destination.

Shift G left by a length of width  w or b of river to new point B.

Join S to B by a straight line representing a taut thread or ray of light that goes in a straight line. SB cuts left bank at H.

Now move B back to G, and H to I across river as horizontal  displacement parallel to x-axis same vector of opposite sense.

Required path is along vectors $(a,b,c).$

Lengths found from similar triangles:

$$ \frac{HE}{SE}=\frac{GK}{KS} = \tan \phi,$$

the inclination angle $\phi$ makes to x-axis.

[image]